# Database connection error MySQL,Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

I am using following setting of dbcp for connection pooling

```
maxActive = 50
maxIdle = 10
minIdle = 2
initialSize = 2
maxWait = 30000
validationQuery="select 1"
testOnBorrow=true
testWhileIdle=true
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=60000
```

Also, I have set auto_reconnect to true in connection URL. I am seeing following error on regular basis.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: 
The last communications with the server was 28810 seconds ago,
which is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. 
You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity
before use in your application, increasing the server configured values
for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property
'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem
```

Does anybody has any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Is autoReconnect being set to true as it suggests?  Are you sure you are actually closing your connections so they are released back to the pool.  Is this from Debug logging?  Does it show up on Error logging?  I think it might just be telling you there is no activity going on so it is closing connections that were hanging open un-needed.

Comment: Also unless you are debugging a problem I would remove the validationQuery, testOnBorrow, testWhileIdle, and timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis params.

Comment: Yes this is from error logging occurring at the time of executing query. Also, it is autoReconnect=true as suggested.

Comment: Ok, then pretty much either the query being called is taking an eternity to complete, or the connection is being being released to the connection pool.

Comment: @BrianC Use of a `validationQuery` is not really a problem. If you use `/* ping */ SELECT 1` then Connector/J will do a simple protocol-ping and not have to run a whole query, etc. Safe and effective. Enabling `autoReconnect=true` hasn't been recommended in a long time, in spite of the text of the error message.

Comment: The key is in the magic number `28810 seconds`: that is 8 hours 10 seconds. I would suspect that you have an 8-hour timeout on a firewall between your application and database servers, but a sane `validationQuery` will eliminate that problem. Are you sure this configuration is actually in effect? Have you confirmed via JMX that these settings have taken effect?

Comment: I did not say it was a problem.  Just that it was not needed.

Comment: thanks for reply but i have suffering the JDBC driver i am using upgrade version of MySQL connector its working fine